# system argumentoutofrange exception when dynamic binding WPF listview

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception

My desktop application has a listview(gridview) that is created like this:

```
class ObjItem
{
   list<string> Attributes;
}
ObservableCollection<ObjItem> Rows;
ItemSource = Rows;
```

Everytime when `Rows is updated I dynamically bind new columns with code:

```
int index = 0;
foreach (var column in columns)
{
   gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
   {
       Header = column,
       DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(string.Format("{0}[{1}]", "Attributes", index++))
   });
}
```

Each time when `Rows`was updated `Attributes` was updated correctly by `Add` some strings. However the exception of `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` was reported and VS debugger was able to catch this exception if we set debugger to catch all exceptions.

"A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

If `Attributes` were reserved with some empty string value with `Attributes.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat("", 20)) it works fine without any exception being caught.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing index to -1 instead of 0:

```
int index = -1;
```

it looks like you are incrementing too early.